# How to automatically add href on image with its same src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How to Automatically add `href` to image with its same `src` and custom `title` attribute to every image on a `div`?

I need to convert every image on a custom `div` like:

```
<div id="galery">
  <img src="images/img.jpg">
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="galery">
  <a href="images/img.jpg"><img src="images/img.jpg" title="a title"></a>
  <p>title</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `after()` function to add the title after the image, and the `wrap()` function to surround the image with a hyperlink:

```js
$("#galery img").each(function() {
  this.title = "a title";
  $(this).after("<p>title</p>");
  $(this).wrap('<a href="' + this.src + '"></a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="galery">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
var $img = jQuery("#galery img");
var $anchor = jQuery("<a title='a title'>").attr("href", $img.attr("src"));

$img.wrap($anchor).parent().after("<p>title</p>");
```

Or to handle multiple images you could use:

```
jQuery("#galery img").each(function() {
    var $img = $(this);
    var $anchor = jQuery("<a title='a title'>").attr("href", $img.attr("src"));
    $img.wrap($anchor).parent().after("<p>title</p>");
});
```